# Perseo fe docker instance fail to start

Tags: mongodb, docker, fiware, complex-event-processing, fiware-perseo

I am facing with the following issue:
I am trying to deploy FIWARE-Perseo to my Centos 7 server as docker instances. Although the perseocore instance runs without a problem, it doesn't happen the same with the perseo front end. It is created but fails to start. From the logs it is clear that the problem is associated to the mongodb:

> Changing PERSEO_CORE_URL to environment value: http://localhost:8080
>   Changing PERSEO_ORION_URL to environment value:
>   http://myip:1026/v1/updateContext Changing PERSEO_LOG_LEVEL to
>   environment value: debug time=2018-06-01T14:36:02.691Z | lvl=INFO |
>   corr=n/a | trans=n/a | op=start | comp=perseo-fe | msg=starting perseo
>   the server/replset/mongos options are deprecated, all their options
>   are supported at the top level of the options object
>   [poolSize,ssl,sslValidate,sslCA,sslCert,sslKey,sslPass,sslCRL,autoReconnect,noDelay,keepAlive,connectTimeoutMS,family,socketTimeoutMS,reconnectTries,reconnectInterval,ha,haInterval,replicaSet,secondaryAcceptableLatencyMS,acceptableLatencyMS,connectWithNoPrimary,authSource,w,wtimeout,j,forceServerObjectId,serializeFunctions,ignoreUndefined,raw,bufferMaxEntries,readPreference,pkFactory,promiseLibrary,readConcern,maxStalenessSeconds,loggerLevel,logger,promoteValues,promoteBuffers,promoteLongs,domainsEnabled,keepAliveInitialDelay,checkServerIdentity,validateOptions,appname,auth]
>   the server/replset/mongos options are deprecated, all their options
>   are supported at the top level of the options object
>   [poolSize,ssl,sslValidate,sslCA,sslCert,sslKey,sslPass,sslCRL,autoReconnect,noDelay,keepAlive,connectTimeoutMS,family,socketTimeoutMS,reconnectTries,reconnectInterval,ha,haInterval,replicaSet,secondaryAcceptableLatencyMS,acceptableLatencyMS,connectWithNoPrimary,authSource,w,wtimeout,j,forceServerObjectId,serializeFunctions,ignoreUndefined,raw,bufferMaxEntries,readPreference,pkFactory,promiseLibrary,readConcern,maxStalenessSeconds,loggerLevel,logger,promoteValues,promoteBuffers,promoteLongs,domainsEnabled,keepAliveInitialDelay,checkServerIdentity,validateOptions,appname,auth]
>   time=2018-06-01T14:36:02.789Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=n/a | trans=n/a |
>   op=checkDB | comp=perseo-fe | msg=connect failed to connect to server
>   [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED
>   127.0.0.1:27017] time=2018-06-01T14:36:02.790Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=n/a | trans=n/a | op=start | comp=perseo-fe | msg=failed to connect to
>   server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect
>   ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017] time=2018-06-01T14:36:02.792Z | lvl=INFO
>   | corr=n/a | trans=n/a | op=perseo | comp=perseo-fe | msg=starting
>   perseo time=2018-06-01T14:36:02.792Z | lvl=FATAL | corr=n/a |
>   trans=n/a | op=perseo | comp=perseo-fe | msg=failed to connect to
>   server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect
>   ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]

I have used the instructions from the following link, in a system where Orion and MongoDB were already running as docker instances:
[Running together with Perseo Core and Orion Context Broker](https://github.com/telefonicaid/perseo-fe/blob/master/documentation/deployment.md#running-together-with-perseo-core-and-orion-context-broker)
Thank you very much in advance for any help you can provide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, make sure you use `PERSEO_MONGO_ENDPOINT` instead of `PERSEO_MONGO_HOST`.

Anyway, the following code is an example of a `docker-compose.yml` file you can use to deploy perseo with orion:

```
version: "3"

services:

    mongo:
       image: mongo:3.2
       networks:
         - main
       volumes:
            - ./mongodata:/data/db

    orion:
       image: fiware/orion
       depends_on:
         - mongo
       links:
         - mongo
       ports:
         - "1026:1026"
       networks:
            main:
                aliases:
                    - orion.docker
       command: -dbhost mongo

    perseo-core:
        image: telefonicaiot/perseo-core:1.1.0
        networks:
            main:
                aliases:
                    - perseo-core
        command: -perseo_fe_url perseo-fe:9090

    perseo-fe:
        image: telefonicaiot/perseo-fe:1.5.0
        ports:
            - 9090:9090
        networks:
            main:
                aliases:
                    - perseo-fe
        depends_on:
            - perseo-core
        environment:
            - PERSEO_MONGO_ENDPOINT=mongo
            - PERSEO_CORE_URL=http://perseo-core:8080
            - PERSEO_LOG_LEVEL=debug
            - PERSEO_ORION_URL=http://orion.docker:1026/v1/updateContext
            - PERSEO_SMTP_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
            - PERSEO_SMTP_PORT=465
            - PERSEO_SMTP_SECURE=true
            - PERSEO_SMTP_AUTH_USER=XXXXX@XXXXX.com
            - PERSEO_SMTP_AUTH_PASS=XXXXX
networks:
    main:
        external: true
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help! The change to PERSEO_MONGO_ENDPOINT made the difference! The documentation should be edited by the development team so to correct this. Thank you, again, very much!