# Installation timeout on Perseo Docker Build

Tags: fiware, fiware-perseo

I'm trying to install perseo following the guide from https://github.com/telefonicaid/perseo-core/blob/master/documentation/deployment.md

I guess that I have to install perseo-core first and after I have to install perseo-fe. When I'm trying to deploy perseo-core, I'm getting some errors (probably the issue is on my side).
When I try `docker build -t perseo .`, after few warnings, it seems it hangs at some point:

```
http://mirror.uv.es/mirror/CentOS/7.5.1804/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://mirror.uv.es/mirror/CentOS/7.5.1804/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Operation too slow. Less than 1000 bytes/sec transferred the last 30 seconds')
Trying other mirror.
ftp://ftp.cesca.cat/centos/7.5.1804/extras/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on ftp://ftp.cesca.cat/centos/7.5.1804/extras/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Operation too slow. Less than 1000 bytes/sec transferred the last 30 seconds')
Trying other mirror.
http://ftp.cica.es/CentOS/7.5.1804/extras/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://ftp.cica.es/CentOS/7.5.1804/extras/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Operation too slow. Less than 1000 bytes/sec transferred the last 30 seconds')
Trying other mirror.
http://mirror.airenetworks.es/CentOS/7.5.1804/extras/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://mirror.airenetworks.es/CentOS/7.5.1804/extras/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Operation too slow. Less than 1000 bytes/sec transferred the last 30 seconds')
Trying other mirror.
http://centos.uvigo.es/7.5.1804/extras/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://centos.uvigo.es/7.5.1804/extras/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Operation too slow. Less than 1000 bytes/sec transferred the last 30 seconds')
Trying other mirror.
http://ftp.uma.es/mirror/CentOS/7.5.1804/extras/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://ftp.uma.es/mirror/CentOS/7.5.1804/extras/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Operation too slow. Less than 1000 bytes/sec transferred the last 30 seconds')
```

If I try to install it from rpm, I get the next errors:

```
RPM build errors:
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.1yMNCh (%prep)
[centos@digitanimal-fiware-test-2018 rpm]$ ^C
[centos@digitanimal-fiware-test-2018 rpm]$ sudo ./create-rpm.sh 1 0.1
Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.iyb82M
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/centos/perseo-core/rpm/BUILD
+ echo '[INFO] Preparing installation'
[INFO] Preparing installation
+ rm -Rf /home/centos/perseo-core/rpm/BUILDROOT/perseo-cep-core-0.1-1.x86_64
+ mkdir -p /home/centos/perseo-core/rpm/BUILDROOT/perseo-cep-core-0.1-1.x86_64
+ '[' -d /home/centos/perseo-core/rpm/BUILDROOT/perseo-cep-core-0.1-1.x86_64/usr/share/tomcat/webapps ']'
+ mkdir -p /home/centos/perseo-core/rpm/BUILDROOT/perseo-cep-core-0.1-1.x86_64/usr/share/tomcat/webapps
+ cp -ax /home/centos/perseo-core/rpm/../target/perseo-core-0.1.war /home/centos/perseo-core/rpm/BUILDROOT/perseo-cep-core-0.1-1.x86_64/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/perseo-core.war
cp: cannot stat '/home/centos/perseo-core/rpm/../target/perseo-core-0.1.war': No such file or directory
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.iyb82M (%prep)
RPM build errors:
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.iyb82M (%prep)
```

Any help? Also, if there is any additional information from perseo, could you share the links? I'm using the doc coming from http://fiware-iot-stack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cep/index.html and from github

Thanks

Comment: I created 2 scripts to install Perseo Core and Perseo FrontEnd on Centos 7. Please let me know how can I share them?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're executing `docker build` from a path where there's no visibility for files you're doing `COPY` in your Dockerfile.

For example, if your Dockerfile does: `COPY ./perseo-core/rpm/file.txt, you cannot execute`docker build`from ./perseo-core/other_folder although you do`../`

Try to execute your `docker build` from a higher directory, or simply post your Dockerfile and path where you're executing `docker build`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use the any of the already provided docker images.

First, Telefónica provides the current "stable" images. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50683735/2255503) for more details.

We are working on improving Perseo and having it up to date. This version is available at Docker Hub on the FIWARE organization. In this regard, Perseo has been updated to use a recent version of Esper, NodeJS, Java, ... and now comes with support for NGSIv2. If you want to test this version instead, you can use the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: '3.4'
services:

    perseo-core:
        image: fiware/perseo-core
        environment:
            - PERSEO_FE_URL=http://perseo:9090
            - MAX_AGE=6000
        depends_on:
            - mongo

    perseo:
        image: fiware/perseo
        ports:
            - 9090:9090
        depends_on:
            - perseo-core
        environment:
            - PERSEO_MONGO_ENDPOINT=mongo
            - PERSEO_CORE_URL=http://perseo-core:8080
            - PERSEO_LOG_LEVEL=info
            - PERSEO_ORION_URL=http://orion:1026/
            - PERSEO_SMTP_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
            - PERSEO_SMTP_PORT=465
            - PERSEO_SMTP_SECURE=true
            - PERSEO_SMTP_AUTH_USER=XXXXX@XXXXX.com
            - PERSEO_SMTP_AUTH_PASS=XXXXX

    mongo:
        image: mongo:3.4
        volumes:
            - ./oriondata:/data/db
        command: --nojournal

    orion:
        image: fiware/orion
        depends_on:
            - mongo
        ports:
            - 1026:1026
        command: -dbhost mongo
```